# In vue.js how can I filter products by size, color, category & by selecting each of these categories in step wise slider

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In vue.js how can I filter products by size, color, category & by selecting each of these categories in step-wise slider where I have to select each filter one by one step-wise & at last I need to display the products which pass through the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please share code examples and ask specific questions about where you are stuck. This question is very broad and is difficult to answer.

I'll try to provide an answer as best as I can.

You might have a `ProductList` component that may look something like this:

```
<template>
  <!-- your template -->
</template>

<script>
import RangeSlider from "./RangeSlider";
export default {
  name: "ProductList",
  components: {
    RangeSlider
  },
  data() {
    return {
      products: [],
      filters: {
        color: null,
        size: null,
        category: null
      },
      options: {
        color: ["Red", "Yellow", "Green"],
        size: ["Small", "Medium", "Large"],
        category: ["Men", "Women", "Boy", "Girl"]
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

The `RangeSlider` can use the native `<input type="range" />` control to build the functionality you want.

In this example, it takes a `label` and an array of `options` to build the control, and will emit a `change` event when the user changes the value of the control by sliding, which is captured in `ProductList` to set the filters. You can then use the `filters` object and make an API call to fetch your products.

```
<template>
  <div class="range-slider">
    <label>
      <strong>{{ label }}</strong>
    </label>
    <div>
      <input type="range" min="0" :max="max" step="1" @change="onInputChange" :value="rangeValue">
    </div>
    <div>{{ options[rangeValue] }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "RangeSlider",
  props: ["label", "options"],
  data() {
    return {
      rangeValue: 0
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.onChange(0);
  },
  methods: {
    onInputChange(e) {
      this.onChange(e.target.value);
    },
    onChange(rangeValue) {
      this.rangeValue = rangeValue;
      let selectedOption = this.options[this.rangeValue];
      this.$emit("change", selectedOption);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    max() {
      return this.options.length - 1;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.range-slider {
  padding: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
</style>
```

---

Here is the working example on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/rangesliderwithoptionsexample-6pe10

Comment: Like I have  a lot of products I want to filter  them on the  basis of  size, color & gender , That too like in first step I have a list of colours to select from & after selecting color I am swiped to next step  where I have to select from gender & in step 3 i have to select from  all sizes , & at last I want to display products which meet all these conditions. Can you help me with that as I am struck in creating this filter in Vue,

Comment: Did you try the CodeSandbox example? You can tweak it to achieve what you want.